# How can I get coordinates from a map with SVG Path?

Tags: html, svg, maps

So I need some coordinates. I you open this page: https://www.inatur.no/jakt/5891ac4ee4b0f06b0de95636/blafjellet-jaktfelt-smaviltjakt-i-lierne there is a map option that shows a polygon over an area.

I want to get those paths as normal lat/long coordinates, but I can't find any solution to this.

In the HTML I find this code:

```
<path fill="url(#dojoxUnique1)" stroke="rgb(206, 80, 53)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2.6666666666666665" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" path="M 789,616 789,616 636,580 567,563 510,549 499,547 514,412 522,354 528,309 533,280 541,223 547,180 568,199 584,210 598,213 612,211 620,212 644,218 673,232 707,245 751,232 911,289 957,307 984,340 982,341 985,348 983,353 979,359 973,361 964,369 963,366 960,366 955,363 953,366 957,370 959,381 957,386 961,387 962,389 959,394 961,405 957,405 951,408 949,405 945,404 943,409 945,414 948,417 949,423 948,428 944,431 942,434 946,437 945,450 930,458 928,465 919,472 919,474 913,481 911,482 898,503 891,505 888,508 884,503 876,504 858,514 851,540 847,547 800,571 789,616 Z" d="M 789 616 789 616 636 580 567 563 510 549 499 547 514 412 522 354 528 309 533 280 541 223 547 180 568 199 584 210 598 213 612 211 620 212 644 218 673 232 707 245 751 232 911 289 957 307 984 340 982 341 985 348 983 353 979 359 973 361 964 369 963 366 960 366 955 363 953 366 957 370 959 381 957 386 961 387 962 389 959 394 961 405 957 405 951 408 949 405 945 404 943 409 945 414 948 417 949 423 948 428 944 431 942 434 946 437 945 450 930 458 928 465 919 472 919 474 913 481 911 482 898 503 891 505 888 508 884 503 876 504 858 514 851 540 847 547 800 571 789 616Z" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

Does someone know how I can convert these to lat/long coordinates?

Comment: one observation: you have an error, You have an attribute path. In fact it's a `d` attribute. In order to get the coords you need you may use the `getBBox()` method for the path. This is returning the position (x,y) and the size (width, height) of the path

Comment: I thanks for answering, I have not written this code, I just found the code in the website that I link to above.

Comment: You need to know which mapping was used to convert lat/long physical geographical coordinates to svg coordinates. Then use inverse mapping to get lat/long. If you do not know the mapping, you can estimate it from a few known lat/long-SVG coordinate pairs

Comment: HI Jan, I don't know which mapping, but I can find some points on the maps that corresponds. How should I proceed and how can I do inverse mapping?